# Work around for 3rd party cookies

Tags: ios, asp.net, iis, cookies, android-webview

I own exampleA.com site which uses an authentication cookie.
Another site (which I can ask them to change their web.config) exampleB.com is using one of my pages in an iFrame using a special link and based on that I authenticates the user and creates the cookie for exampleA.com.

I don't have any issues with this implementation for Firefox, IE, and Chrome. But, by default, Safari doesn't allow 3rd party cookies. Therefore, inside the iFrame exampleA.com doesn't load properly. According to webkit.org, Safar allows 3rd party cookies for the sites that user visited within 24 hours. If that's the only issue, I could do some kind of a redirection to solve this.

ExampleB.com has an Android app as well as an iOS app that uses the WebView to load the same underlying sites. It looks like the 24-hour cookie policy won't work for at least the Android app.

Is the only option that I have is to change the exampleA.com to use a cookieless authentication? Any other suggestions?

Comment: Create a token provider URL that ExampleB.com can visit in a quick (full-window) round trip. Set the cookie there. Safari will still accept cookies in the full window, and will still present them in the iFrame if they already exist.

Comment: This still doesn't work in the Android app. The cookie set in the main window will still not be accessible inside an iframe.